# Facebook is asking me to verify my business but I'm not a business

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-login

I have developed an iOS app which has a Facebook login and receives user photos. The login processes authentication using Passport on Node.

I have had the app on the app store for over a year now, and Facebook has recently begun reviewing permissions. I have got all my permissions accepted, and now Facebook have asked me to submit details of my business. This is a problem because I do not have a business, I'm just a developer who has decided to make an app which uses Facebook for authentication.

Does anyone know if I can inform Facebook that I'm not a business, or if I'm even allowed to use Facebook as a platform as a sole developer?

Thanks